# Extract data from image containing table grid using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

**I have images such as the one attached below. I need to extract the data within the grid along with the tabular structure and transform it into a dataframe/csv.**

[image]

I am using OCR to extract the text along with the coordinates but in order to extract the table structure I would like to extract the horizontal and vertical grid lines.

**Is there a method in OpenCV to do that that would generalize well ?**

So far the approaches I've come across are :
1. Hough Lines
2. Extracting Rectangular contours
3. Drawing vertical and horizonal contours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a grid structure  and extract information from all separate area with openCV, check this article [A Box detection algorithm for any image containing boxes](https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-box-detection-algorithm-for-any-image-containing-boxes-756c15d7ed26)

Everything is perfectly explained

Comment: This works quite well but has some inconsistencies in the case of scanned documents. Any idea on how to make the extraction more robust ?

Comment: Glad it was useful!
Could you being more specific about what inconsistencies are you talking  about ?

Comment: Please check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62092264/extract-table-structure-from-image-containing-tables-with-borders?noredirect=1#comment109823399_62092264

Answer (score 1):

With all due respect to @Chrys Bltr, the solution in the link is a little overkill. Here's a simpler solution, so I think:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_rgb = cv2.imread('your/image')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,3,3)

_, ctrs, _ = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
im_h, im_w = img.shape
im_area = im_w * im_h
for ctr in ctrs:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    # Filter contours based on size
    if 0.01 * im_area < w * h < 0.1*im_area:
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

plt.imshow(img_rgb, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

You can store the rectangle information in the filtering process above and then do the OCR within each individual rectangular area.