# Extract table structure from image containing Tables with borders

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to extract the cell locations in the table below.

[image]

I was able to get the contours around the cell positions after applying adaptive thresholding and HoughLines get vertical and horizontal structuring elements. 
Here's my code :

```
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(img_path, file))
img1 = img.copy()


gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bw = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 17, 1)
bw = cv2.bitwise_not(bw)


#detect horizontal lines
horizontalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15, 1))

horizontal = cv2.erode(bw, horizontalStructure)
horizontal = cv2.dilate(horizontal, horizontalStructure)

horizontal = cv2.dilate(horizontal, (1,1), iterations=5)
horizontal = cv2.erode(horizontal, (1,1), iterations=5)


hlines = cv2.HoughLinesP(horizontal, 1, np.pi/180, 20, np.array([]), 20, 2)


for line in hlines :
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        if abs(x1 - x2) > img.shape[1]/4:    
            cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)





#detect vertical lines
verticalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 15))

vertical = cv2.erode(bw, verticalStructure)
vertical = cv2.dilate(vertical, verticalStructure)

vertical = cv2.dilate(vertical, (1,1), iterations=5)
#vertical = cv2.erode(vertical, (1,1), iterations=5)


vlines = cv2.HoughLinesP(vertical, 1, np.pi/180, 20, np.array([]), 20, 2)


for line in vlines :
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        #if abs(y1 - y2) > img.shape[0]/2:
        cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)





# red color boundaries [B, G, R]
lower = [0, 240, 0]
upper = [20, 255, 20]

# create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
lower = np.array(lower, dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array(upper, dtype="uint8")

# find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
# the mask
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(img1, img, mask=mask)



ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask, 40, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

img_area  = img.shape[0] * img.shape[1]

for c in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if w * h > 0.005 * img_area:
        cv2.rectangle(img1, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

[image]

How can I improve this solution? What other approaches can I implement in order to extract the table cells information better and in a more robust manner ?

Comment: Once you have thresholded the image, invert it so the lines are white. Then use cv2.findContours to get the largest contours, removing the contours for the text. Then you can get the bounding boxes of the contours to find each upper left corner if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @fmw42 how should I remove the text contours ? Based on what condition ?

Comment: Based upon area. Discard contours that are smaller than the area of the smallest rectangle

Comment: I am doing that in the code. Once I find the contours I only plot the ones where area is above a certain value

Comment: You can also use morphology to extract just the horizontal lines and then again to extract just the vertical lines. Then combine and get the contours of the large white regions. In my comment above, get the contours of the large white regions after thresholding and do not invert. That was a mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the contour code above when I first read your post. I forgot to scroll down.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing. First extract the horizontal and vertical line segments and then superimpose them to get the grid. I'll try to get the contours without inverting the image and see how that works.

Comment: explain please what are you aiming to enhance ? It is the box area that cut some character ?

Comment: I'm trying to extract the bounding boxes around each table cell. I am somewhat able to accomplish that but the results isnt as clean as I would like it to be.

Comment: Thank you so much for your code.. it helped me in detecting tables

Answer (score -1):

for each box detected , take a wider area to get along with an arbitrary error treshold (in n pixel width, like 5 pixel), you should be able to detect every text content